# Confused about career path

Tags: programming

My question probably will be blocked. Anyway, my question is how much programming is there in the security field. 
Useless:
I really hate programming, actually I can translate code from C to python and Java and a bit of assembly to C(and vice versa). But I can't write my program the only port scanner that I have write was on Python I can't do it on C nor Java. I understand the basics without any confusion, but I can't learn algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, this question will get nuked, so here's a quick answer before that happens :)

Programming can be useful in certain fields of security, and less so in others.  So if you do application security work (advising/working with developers) then it's important that you have a good understanding of what they do and can work with them to come up with practical solutions.

Also if you're a penentration/security tester being able to write your own scripts for automation is important and also understanding roughly what a piece of code does and how is useful when attacking systems.

For other types of security work (e.g. policy stuff, higher level advice and guidance) programming is less likely to be important...